# Manually handling auto increment in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

We have a products database that contains our inventory, that will be merging with a new (growing) catalog from another product source. Products from source 1 currently have IDs from 0 - 50k (every month 10-15 new products are added). Products from source 2 that hasn't been added to our inventory yet start at ID: 1000000+ on their side. I was thinking to maintain ease of integration and recognition of which product is coming from which catalog, that we manually handle auto incrementing the product id in our products table.

In our  before insert trigger, we would check for the following:

***pseudocode***:

```
if (product_source = 'internal_catalog') {
 new.id = SELECT max(id) + 1 FROM products where product_source = 'internal_catalog';
} else {
 new.id = new.original_product_id; -- original_product_id will always be unique and > 1000000;
}
```

To me, this theoretically should work but obviously I'm worried about concurrency errors and collisions. From what I can see, the above trigger will lock the table so there shouldn't be any collisions. Are there any issues with the above approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pseudocode you showed will not lock the table, and will be susceptible to race conditions during concurrent inserts.

There is, in general, no way to do custom auto-increment behavior without locking the whole table, because to avoid those race conditions you have to block concurrent inserts.

The alternative is to use some external increment mechanism to generate new id values. For example, create a key in a memcached instance and use the atomic increment-and-get call to get new unique id values. Don't do this in your trigger, do it the application before you execute your INSERT.

But the best practice to forget about using the auto-increment as some kind of enumerated type. It's required to be unique—that's all. Not sequential or consecutive.